# VCL bug with FireDAC & CmdExecMode = amCancelDialog?

Tags: delphi, vcl, firedac

I have encountered a strange issue with FireDAC when CmdExecMode is set to amCancelDialog and doing a certain set of actions. The issue is that doing these actions leaves the application in a very strange state in which clicking anywhere on the form or using the TAB key will raise a "Cannot focus a disabled or invisible window" exception. This state also makes the mouse cursor not change when for example hovering over a TEdit.

The exception occurs because the application is trying to set focus to a TStringGrid in a form which is no longer visible.

The following sequence of events triggers this strange state:
- Open a form with ShowModal
- Double-click a TStringGrid in the opened form which sets a ModalResult
- Open a query

Is this some sort of VCL bug or what is really happening here? Is there a way of getting out of this state?

Delphi version is XE7.

---

Stack trace of exception:

```
:75d1b727 KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x58
Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.SetFocus
Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.FocusControl(???)
Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.SetFocus
Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.MouseDown(mbLeft,[ssLeft],100,40)
Vcl.Controls.TControl.DoMouseDown((513, (), 1, (), 100, 40, (), (100, 40), (), 0),mbLeft,[])
Vcl.Controls.TControl.WMLButtonDown((513, (), 1, (), 100, 40, (), (100, 40), (), 0))
Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.WMLButtonDown(???)
Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc((513, 1, 2621540, 0, 1, 0, (), 100, 40, (), 0, 0, ()))
Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc((513, 1, 2621540, 0, 1, 0, (), 100, 40, (), 0, 0, ()))
Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc(???)
System.Classes.StdWndProc(6885476,513,1,2621540)
Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage(???)
:005efbe2 TCustomForm.FocusControl + $66
```

Code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option,
  FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.Phys.PG,
  FireDAC.Phys.PGDef, FireDAC.VCLUI.Async, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait, FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt, Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client, FireDAC.Comp.UI, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
    FDGUIxAsyncExecuteDialog1: TFDGUIxAsyncExecuteDialog;
    FDGUIxWaitCursor1: TFDGUIxWaitCursor;
    query: TFDQuery;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Form2.ShowModal;
   query.Open('SELECT * FROM table');
   query.Close;
end;

end.
```

---

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    procedure StringGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.StringGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ModalResult := mrOk;
end;

end.
```